# Manipulate slider from predefined array

Tags: manipulate

This is a minimal example of what I want to make work:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
coeff = Array[a, 2];
arange = {#, -1, 1} & /@ coeff;
X = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, 1, 2}];
Manipulate[
coeff = Array[a, 2];
{coeff[[1]] X[[1]] + coeff[[2]] X[[2]], 
a[1] X[[1]] + a[2] X[[2]]},
##] & @@ arange
```

I would like to make the first option, namely `coeff[[1]] X[[1]] + coeff[[2]] X[[2]]` work like `a[1] X[[1]] + a[2] X[[2]]`. However, only the latter updates the values of the parameters.

context: I generate a system of ODEs with a large number of parameters. These parameters are generated via `Array`, and I'd like to put such a system into a Manipulate. Generating them via `Array` is very useful and convenient because the indices are used to define the equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
With[{coeff = Array[a, 2]},
 Manipulate[{coeff[[1]] X[[1]] + coeff[[2]] X[[2]]
    ,a[1] X[[1]] + a[2] X[[2]]}, ##]] & @@ arange
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks indeed. For some reason logic would tell me that the coeff=Array[a,2] inside the Manipulate would be equivalent... of course, my logic is wrong.